# What regex could I use to extract words that are surrounded by specific characters?

Tags: python, html, find

I need to extract some usernames from a list. I work in Jupyter Notebooks and use Python. I believe that regex would be the way to go, but feel free to recommend a different approach.

The names are surrounded by the same characters. The following characters precede the names:

```
bold;">
```

and the following characters are directly behind the names:

```
</a>
```

Here is a small fraction of the data that I would like to extract names from:

```
<a class="model" href="#" style="color:#FF6EC7;font-family:'Verdana';font-weight:bold;">HoneyxLover</a>,
  <a class="model model_img" href="#" style="background-image:url('https://img.mfcimg.com/photos2/383/38344261/avatar.300x300.jpg');"></a>,
<a class="model" href="#" style="color:#FF1CAE;font-family:'Comic Sans MS', 'ChalkboardSE-Regular';font-weight:bold;">RubinRosey</a>,
  <a class="model model_img" href="#" style="background-image:url('https://img.mfcimg.com/photos2/228/22826417/avatar.300x300.jpg');"></a>,
```

Comment: [Have you tried using an HTML parser instead?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3001761)

Comment: Just use requests and BeautifulSoup

Comment: The comment of @jonrsharpe is wise. If your source is in HTML it's better to use an HTML parser like BeautifulSoup.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `BeautifulSoup` instead of regex:

```
# Python env: pip install bs4
# Anaconda env: conda install bs4

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """<a class="model" href="#" style="color:#FF6EC7;font-family:'Verdana';font-weight:bold;">HoneyxLover</a>,
  <a class="model model_img" href="#" style="background-image:url('https://img.mfcimg.com/photos2/383/38344261/avatar.300x300.jpg');"></a>,
<a class="model" href="#" style="color:#FF1CAE;font-family:'Comic Sans MS', 'ChalkboardSE-Regular';font-weight:bold;">RubinRosey</a>,
  <a class="model model_img" href="#" style="background-image:url('https://img.mfcimg.com/photos2/228/22826417/avatar.300x300.jpg');"></a>,"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

for link in soup.select('a[class="model"]'):
    print(link.text)
```

Output:

```
HoneyxLover
RubinRosey
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is with `re` module (RegEx):

```py
import re
string = """<a class="model" href="#" style="color:#FF6EC7;font-family:'Verdana';font-weight:bold;">HoneyxLover</a>,
  <a class="model model_img" href="#" style="background-image:url('https://img.mfcimg.com/photos2/383/38344261/avatar.300x300.jpg');"></a>,
<a class="model" href="#" style="color:#FF1CAE;font-family:'Comic Sans MS', 'ChalkboardSE-Regular';font-weight:bold;">RubinRosey</a>,
  <a class="model model_img" href="#" style="background-image:url('https://img.mfcimg.com/photos2/228/22826417/avatar.300x300.jpg');"></a>,"""
print(re.findall(r'bold;">(.*)</a>',string))
```

This code is with `xml` module:

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

string = """<a class="model" href="#" style="color:#FF6EC7;font-family:'Verdana';font-weight:bold;">HoneyxLover</a>,
  <a class="model model_img" href="#" style="background-image:url('https://img.mfcimg.com/photos2/383/38344261/avatar.300x300.jpg');"></a>,
<a class="model" href="#" style="color:#FF1CAE;font-family:'Comic Sans MS', 'ChalkboardSE-Regular';font-weight:bold;">RubinRosey</a>,
  <a class="model model_img" href="#" style="background-image:url('https://img.mfcimg.com/photos2/228/22826417/avatar.300x300.jpg');"></a>,"""

split_list = string.strip(',').split(',\n')
for i in split_list:
    element = ET.fromstring(i.strip())
    if element.attrib['class']=='model':
        print(element.text)
```